# What is the best loop to use for a big list?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I was never any good with loops for some reason, but can not live without them. following is the code I use to read a list of user details in XXXX:XXXX format. (not 4 chars exactly but you know) I can load the first user and am able to split the string and add from the colon back to listbox1, but just cannot get a loop to work and cant walk away until this is done. Normally a break from work solves the war but not an option right now.

```
    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim R As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim str As String() = R.ReadLine().Split(":")
    Dim Info As String = str(1)

    ListBox1.Items.Add(Info)



    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    TextBox5.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    R.Close()

End Sub
```

I know its right in front of me. 
I just tried a for next loop which I thought for sure would work and didnt.
Please help. Someone

Comment: While I see  you got your answer, you should at least include the loop code you tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this loop.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
  While Not sr.EndOfStream
    ListBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(":")(1))
  End While
End Using
```

Comment: This worked perfectly :) Love this place because of people like.

Answer (score 2):

No need for loop:

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim items = Array.ConvertAll(lines, Function(line) line.Split(":"c)(1))
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)
```